# 401 Full Authentication Error Rally

Tags: rally

While executing my rally scripts. I encounter this problem a lot of times. Once my script runs fine but the next time I run it, I get a 401 Full authentication error required error. This also happens while running a certain script. It works fine for some period of time and then suddenly it abruptly throws me this error.I am almost sure that is some problem with Rally and not on my end. Has anyone encountered this before? Any fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete shot in the dark, but maybe try bypassing the CDN using 'us1' instead of 'rally1' ?

More can be found here: http://help.rallydev.com/rally-ip-addresses-and-cdn-networks

Otherwise, I haven't seen that error before. - Dave